# After upgrading to 16.10, 3840x2160 resolution not being detected

Tags: upgrade, xorg, display-resolution

I have a Seiki 39" 4k monitor that worked out of the box with Ubuntu 14.04 and has worked with every upgrade since then, until I upgraded to 16.10, after which it now starts up in 1920x1080.

By scanning my Xorg.0.log before and after the upgrade, I can see that it does detect the 3840 resolution through DDC, but complains that `EDID timing clock 297.00 exceeds claimed max 115MHz, fixing`.  The older logs (from 16.04) have the same line, though, but it worked then.

```
[   389.050] (WW) EDID timing clock 297.00 exceeds claimed max 115MHz, fixing
[   389.050] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEK", prod id 0
[   389.050] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[   389.050] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[   389.050] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   389.050] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x0.0  297.00  3840 4016 4104 4400  2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
... ( other modes omited )
[   389.050] (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
[   389.468] (WW) EDID timing clock 297.00 exceeds claimed max 115MHz, fixing
... ( repeats same block again )
```

I'm using the integrated video driver on an Intel Xeon E3-1200.

By using the information in the `Xorg.0.log`, I found the right incantations to add the mode with the correct modeline through xrandr, and I can do that manually after boot.  I am aware that I can fix this by adding a manual configuration file (though I haven't tried this).  I would like to figure out how I can make this fix on a deeper level, or at least know why exactly this stopped working.